# How to find which pages use a certain view?

Tags: 7, views

I am working on a site that has a lot of views with multiple displays, and to make life easier for our team we are trying to document where views are in use; including view blocks.

In other words, I want a simple way to know which pages use a certain view for each view.  The site also has views that are enabled but not in use on any page, so it would be nice to be able to find out which ones may be candidates for deletion to make administration easier.

Comment: Is the `/admin/structure/views` page not sufficient enough to provide you with the data you're looking for? Inside your *View name* do you have multiple displays?

Comment: Drupal Version?

Comment: @ChrisHappy - Drupal 7.50

Comment: @DMAC - no this does not tell me where blocks are being displayed.  Also, many of the views do have multiple displays.

Comment: If you're ok with doing it manually, enable the contextual links core module. It takes you to the display being used. But it probably won't work for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and enable the **Web Profiler** module that comes with Devel. This module will tell you which view is being used when you visit a page.

Alternatively, you could try the answers from here, [Where are my views being used?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169352/where-are-my-views-being-used/169354#169354)

Comment: I can't find a way to do this in Drupal 7.